# Code is suspetible to XSS, how do I fix using different tags?

Tags: php, xss

I am practising in a VM to improve my knowledge on producing secure code methodology and am stuck on fixing this vulnerable code snippet:

```
<div class="col post-addresses>
{{ post.content|striptags(<>)|raw }}
</div>
```

I understand the `raw` disables the encoding. What does the `striptags` do and also how does using `md2html` help?

Would using `md2html` in this context below help?

```
<div class="col post-addresses>
{{ post.content|md2html}}
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that twig your using there? Afaik twig escapes stuff by default so surely {{ post.content }} is sufficient? If it is twig raw doesn't remove encoding, it's how to stop it escaping (which would be the source of the insecurity in your example)

Comment: @Clint Thanks for this. I didn't try `{{ post.content }}` but would `{{ post.content|md2html}}` work on its own? Yes, this is twig

Comment: What are you expecting in post.content? Should it only contain text? md2html converts markdown to html so if you aren't expecting markdown and only expecting text I'd just go {{ post.content }} and leave twig to escape it for you